# Unlocked Packages NO-namespace LWC not being retrieved. Apex visible

Tags: lightning-web-components, unlocked-package

I'm looking to inspect the LWC components in a public unlocked package with no namespace prefix but can't seem to retrieve them. Apex code is wide open so I was confused as to why lightning components were to be hidden. I tested using VS Code and Sublime 3/Haoide and deployed a test LWC in both. I could retrieve the changes deployed from one IDE to the other for my custom component, but the unlocked package lwc components never come back. Is this how it works or am I missing something?